# Difference between paused property of SKScene and SKView

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene, skview

I am pausing my SKScene using the following code:

```
self.paused = YES;
```

However, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21593852/2043580) by [Andrey Gordeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1321917/andrey-gordeev), one can also pause a scene using this line:

```
self.view.paused = YES;
```

I would like to understand what difference it would make to call the either (or both) to pause a scene.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pausing `SKView` stops calling `update:` method for `SKScene`.

Pausing `SKScene` doesn't do that.

I usually pause both `SKScene` and `SKView`

**EDIT:**

As of `iOS9` pausing the scene will pause the `update:` method.

Comment: I confirmed this by using NSLog() in the update method. Thanks Andrey for clearing this up.

Comment: Pausing SKScene stops all actions running on the node and its children. Therefore both are usually called together.

Comment: This is not the case anymore... In iOS9, the `update:` method is not executed while the scene is paused. You could make an edit about that for the future readers. The other part (about SKView) is of course correct and I guess that will never change :)

Comment: @Whirlwind go ahead and edit an answer! Unfortunately, I don't work with `SpriteKit` now :)

Comment: I'm developing a game with gravitation simulations and actually the difference is noticeable. If you pause/unpause the SKView quickly you get an uncomfortable jitter, like a bug. Pausing/unpausing the scene itself it's a lot smoother.

Answer (score 2):

The effect is the same. You still have the paused property on the scene because it's a subclass of SKNode and the scene may need to be paused during transitions, either through the SKView setting that controls whether scenes are paused during transitions or manually.

I would wager that pausing the view would also be able to "freeze" a currently running transition, which is about the only thing you can't pause by pausing the scene(s) alone.

Therefore pausing the view may also pause all internal timers and draw calls, so a paused view may be better to conserve battery, though that's a guess based on how cocos2d handles a paused director vs paused scene.

Comment: The effect is not the same if you do calculations in `update:` method