# SpriteKit SKAction pause lag

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a spawn action and I was using `NSTimer` to create it, but I changed it to an SKAction so that it would stop when the scene is paused:

```
let SpawnAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5), SKAction.runBlock(Spawn)])
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SpawnAction))
```

Now the problem is the lag that exist on the `waitForDuration` part of the code I think, as it won't work right after the scene is unpaused.

This is the code I'm using to pause/unpause the game:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if (node.name == "Pause") {
            PauseLabel.removeFromParent()
            self.addChild(ResumeLabel)
            self.runAction(SKAction.runBlock(self.pauseGame))
        }
        else if (node.name == "Resume") {
            self.view!.paused = false
            self.addChild(PauseLabel)
            ResumeLabel.removeFromParent()
        }
        else {
            //Other code...
        }
    }
}

func pauseGame() {
    self.view!.paused = true
}
```

I would like someone to tell me the way to properly pause/unpause a SpriteKit game, as all the methods I got off the internet didn't work properly for me. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381088/difference-between-paused-property-of-skscene-and-skview

Comment: Thanks! I always thought `self.view.paused` was the method to use in SpriteKit, but `self.paused` seems to work a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if this will work for you. but under the `didMoveToView` function within the selected handler for the button i use to pause:

i used `self.gameState = .Pause`
 as well as used `self.physicsWorld.speed = 0`

these both stop the game view and the physicsworld helps stop any of the skactions that may be running on your sprites.

hope this helps you.