# Stop button in sprite kit objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios8, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I build a game in sprite kit and all my sksprite node moving with adding force `cgvector`. 
I want to add a stop button to the game but if I will stop all the nodes I will not be able to return the force they had. so i can't stop the game and play again from the same point. 
So somebody know how its possible to save a force on nodes? Or how I can to the stop button?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SKPhysicsWorld` object that you have has a property called `speed`.

from Apple.com:

> The default value is 1.0, which means the simulation runs at normal speed. A value other than the default changes the rate at which time passes in the physics simulation. For example, a speed value of 2.0 indicates that time in the physics simulation passes twice as fast as the scene’s simulation time. A value of 0.0 pauses the physics simulation.

So, essentially you could keep the force applied to all your nodes but effectively "pause" the physics simulation.

---

Alternatively, you could use the `paused` property that will stop ALL actions (not just the physics ones using force)

So if you would use the speed property:

```
self.physicsWorld.speed = 0.0;
```

this works pretty nice if you have quite a bit going on, or if you want to make a method that incrementally slows down things for slow-motion effects. Since you don't have to actually make the physicsWorld object in sprite kit (it is initialized when the scene is made), this is all you have to do.

And pausing everything isn't very complicated either:

```
self.scene.view.paused = YES;
```

Comment: thanks. its working. another question: i can stop skaction and when i want to stop stopping it?

Comment: sure. you just make the `paused` property `NO` to continue

Comment: i want to stop spasific action. not all of them. its passable?

Comment: Well, every SKAction has a `speed` property as well, so you could turn that to 0 to pause that specific action, and then when you want to continue, you would change `speed` back to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use SKView's paused property:

```
self.scene.view.paused = YES;
```

This will stop all actions and physics simulation.

As answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593198/pausing-a-sprite-kit-scene)

Comment: it do stop all the nods but how can i return to game? how can i stop the stop ?

Comment: this code only stop the view the dots are still moving it just cause that i will not able to see it

Answer (score 0):

A SKSpriteNode has a dictionary property called userData. You can store your dx and dy velocity there for later retrieval.

If all your nodes in the view are to stop moving, you can enumerate through all of them using:

```
for(SKSpriteNode *object in self.children) {
    // set velocity of each node
}
```

If only some of your nodes need to undergo the velocity change, you would need to add each one of the effected nodes to an array and enumerate that array.