# I'm Trying to Pause a Sprite Kit Game on Exiting The App

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I can pause the game I have created no problem while I'm in the app. However, when I try and call the pause function I have created in the `applicationWillResignActive` function in App Delegate, it doesn't work, at all. So this is my code that I am trying to use in my App Delegate File.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    GamePlayScene.instance.isPaused = true
    print("Game is Paused")
}
```

The `print` Statement gets called so I know the function is getting called. However, the game still stays active. I'm trying to call the same `isPaused` function that I am using in my `GamePlayScene`.

One thing that works is if I just use the normal pause feature in SpriteKit but, I can't find a way to resume the game after I open the app. For example, I can use this.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    pause()
    print("Game is Paused")
}
```

This seems to work, but the whole app just opens up frozen and there is no way to keep going. What do y'all think?

Comment: Where's your implementation of `applicationDidBecomeActive` to unpause the game?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pausing a sprite kit scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593198/pausing-a-sprite-kit-scene)

Comment: The system automatically pauses and unpauses when leaving and returning.  You need to set pause to true on return

Comment: ApplicationDidBecomeActive is called in AppDelegate. And I have set the pause function to true when returning to the game.

Comment: Did it work?  If not the notification hits the gamescene after it hits didbecomeactive

Comment: It did not work. It literally just doesn’t do anything. Ugh. So frustrating. Thinking of just handing over all the code to see if anyone can fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Since I don't see anyone else that has the answer when involving a SpriteKit Game, I will post the answer. This is my code.

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedCameBack), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

@objc func appMovedCameBack() {
    print("App Came Back!")

    self.scene?.isPaused = true

    GamePlayController.instance.pauseBtn?.alpha = 0

    createPausePanel()
}
```

I am calling the function where I created the PausePanel and adding it to the scene. That is the createPausePanel() function. I am also setting the scene.isPaused = true. This is how I solved my issue.

Comment: I will also say that I added all of this code to my main GamePlayScene